# Can I use raspi-lora with The Things Network for a Raspberry end node

Tags: raspberry-pi, iot, adafruit, lora, lorawan

I am trying to create a Raspberry Pi 3 end node (NOT GATEWAY) with the [Adafruit RFM96W](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3073) module and [raspi-lora](https://pypi.org/project/raspi-lora/) library but it seems that the library has no configurable APPSKEY, NWKSKEY, DEVADDR and etc., so I won't be able to receive downlinks from [The Things Network](https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/), which is what I want. Does any of you have ideas on how I can do it? Or do you know other libraries that can be used in my case?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two connection standards for LoRaWAN. [One is OTAA (the default) the other is ABP](https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/forum/t/what-is-the-difference-between-otaa-and-abp-devices/2723/2).

- OTAA = Over The Air Activiation
- ABP = Activation By Personalisation

OTAA uses only the DevEUI, APPEui and APPKEY.

ABP also needs the APPSKEY, NWSKEY and DEVADDR provided because it doesn't get those assigned by the network. OTAA does get this dynamically assigned.

If your software stack doesn't allow for ABP the solution is to use OTAA. I haven't heard about a case where one is intrinsically better than the other so just use OTAA.

[Here](https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/docs/devices/registration.html) is what TTN says about connecting to them.

---

It seems that the library you are using is only meant for LoRa. LoRaWAN is a network layer on top of LoRa. You need to find a software stack which handles the LoRaWAN network layer to connect to TTN.